# Form submits for final object in a loop every time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have a loop which outputs a list of categories and creates a button which summons a Bootstrap Modal for confirmation. Once confirmed the form submits, but thats where it goes wrong. The form always submits the last item in the list rather than the one selected. As you can see below, i have output the values to console and they output the correct values each time.

For example, there are currently 9 Categories and therefore 9 buttons.

- I select the first category to be deleted - Category{"id":1;"name":'Music'}
- The console outputs:

  1

  Music
- Bootstrap Modal displays "Delete Category: Music"
- When I confirm this is the object I want to delete, it deletes the 9th category.

### What am i doing wrong?

Loop:

```
<table class='table table-striped' id="datatable-table" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th width="100px"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{ route('categories.show', $category->id) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-danger delete-category-modal" value="{{$category->id}}"
                                data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#deleteModal"
                                data-backdrop="static"
                                data-name ="{{$category->name}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Modal:

```
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Category</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            {{ Form::model($category, ['route' => ['categories.destroy', $category->id], 'method' => 'delete']) }}
            {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'name' => 'edit-btn']) }}
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Script:

```
$('button.delete-category-modal').on('click', function (e) {
            // Make sure the click of the button doesn't perform any action
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the modal by ID
            var modal = $('#deleteModal');

            // Set the value of the title fields
                modal.find('.modal-title').text('Delete Category: ' + $(this).data('name'))

            // Update the action of the form
            modal.find('form').attr('DELETE', '/categories/'+ $(this).val());
                console.log($(this).data('name'))
                console.log($(this).val())
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved my own problem, on the modal:

> {{ Form::model($category, ['route' => ['categories.destroy',
>   $category->id], 'method' => 'delete']) }}

$category->id should rather be 'null'

so that jQuery can overright it with the selected value